# python: in put lists from keyboard

Tags: python

write a python program to merge two sorted lists, try to input the values of these two lists from keyboard, but when begin running, try to input the first value, it errors:

> enter a integer of list1:1
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "C:/Python/PythonProject/mergeTwoLists_leetcode.py", line 20, in `<module>`
>
> **list1[i] = input("enter a integer of list1:")**
>
> **IndexError: list assignment index out of range**

the program is :

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val = x
        elf.next = None

class MergeTwoLists(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self,l1,l2):
        if not li or not l2:
            return l1 or l2
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next,l2)
            return l1
        else:
            l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1,l2.next)
            return l2

#input the two integer lists
list1 = []
for i in range(0,6):
    list1[i] = input("enter a integer of list1:")
head = ListNode(list1[0])
p = head
for j in list1[1:]:
    node = ListNode(j)
    p.next = node
    p = p.next
l1 = head

list2 = []
for i in range(0,6):
    list2[i] = input("enter an integer of list2:")
head = ListNode(list2[0])
p = head
for j in list2[1:]:
    node = ListNode(j)
    p.next = node
    p = p.next
l2 = head

list_result = MergeTwoLists().mergeTwoLists(l1,l2)
print("the list result:")
print(list_result)
```

could you help me for that

Comment: FWIW, unless you have some complicated merging logic, merging lists is as easy as: `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]`, which would produce `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized list1 to an empty list

```
list1 = []
```

In order to add a new item to the end of the list use append()

```
for i in range(0,6):
   list1.append(input("enter a integer of list1:"))
```

In your example

```
for i in range(0,6):
   list1[i] = input("enter a integer of list1:")
```

You were getting an IndexError because you were trying to access an index in list1 that doesnt exist, since the length of an empty list is zero.

(FYI this answer is specific to your error, not the rest of your code)

Docs:https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
for i in range(0,6):
    list1.append(input("enter a integer of list1:"))
for i in range(0,6):
    list2.append(input("enter an integer of list2:"))

total_list = list1 + list2
total_list.sort()
```

It's erroring because list1 is an empty list so your position is nonexisting

Answer (score -2):

using `eval` function will help you input a list

```
listos = eval(input('enter a comma seperated list))
listos.split()
```

`split()` is used to `sep` the list with comma and enclose it.